# How to make Ace editor expand fully vertically

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I would like to disable the vertical scrollbar in the Ace editor and to make the editor expand to the size of the document (hence not needing the scrollbar). How could this be done? I am assuming the height of the document is needed and some re-sizing but Ace may have something native.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/kitchen-sink/layout.js#L103
But if document takes more than 2-3 window heights, it will be very slow

Comment: Thank you, yes, I have changed my design to not need Ace to expand - now I realise it only renders what you can see.